# "Invalid base class" error when trying to inherit from derived struct (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I've got a "Base" struct, an "NPC" struct derived from the "Base". All works perfectly fine. But when I try to create a new struct called "PC" from the "NPC" struct, I get an error: "invalid base class".
What's the problem? Is it not possible to create a struct from a derived struct?

```
struct Base
{
    char* name = 0;

    int MaxHP = 0;
    int CurrHP = 0;
};


struct NPC : Base
{
    int gold = 0;
    int stats[];
};

struct PC : NPC // I get the error here
{
    unsigned int ID = 0;
};
```

Comment: `int stats[];` is not legal in `c++`. You must specify the fixed size at compile time.

Comment: @drescherjm I cannot believe I missed that, thanks a lot!

Comment: Compile your code with the `-pedantic-errors` flag (for GCC or Clang) or `/permissive-` (for MSVC). It will fail directly when you try to use such a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote:

```
struct NPC : Base
{
    int gold = 0;
    int stats[]; //NOT VALID, this is a definition and size must be known
};
```

This is **not valid** as from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type):

> Any of the following contexts requires type T to be complete:

> - declaration of a **non-static class data member** of type T;

But the type of the non-static data member `stats` is incomplete and hence the error.

Comment: Might want to add that it complains only on the base class usage, because OP's compiler is using a non-standard compiler extension for flexible array members, but even that extension doesn't allow for such a class to be a base.

Answer (score -3):

> Yes, a struct can inherit from a class. The difference between the class and struct keywords is just a change in the default private/public specifiers.
> --> Here you need to specify the public keyword !

```
  struct Base
{
    char* name = 0;

    int MaxHP = 0;
    int CurrHP = 0;
};


struct NPC : public Base
{
    int gold = 0;
    int stats[];
};

struct PC :  public NPC 
    unsigned int ID = 0;
};
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, it's the `int stats[];` that's illegal.

Comment: No, `public` is not needed here. All the inheritance is implicitly public because these are all `struct`s. More generally, this code would be legal (aside from the `int stats[];` even if all the inheritance was private, although the result would not be particularly useful.